# Link to generic stackexchange.com profile from chat.stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, chat, stackexchange.com

The chat system has profiles per user.  In my current chat [user profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/101/zoredache), a user has the option to select which site to use as the parent user, right now I link to [my profile on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/users/984/zoredache), but I would really like to either select the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/10673/zoredache) as the default or have that listed in addition to a selected site profile.

Current

[image: Chat profile]

Improved Chat profile

[image: Improved]

Comment: You're a mod on Server Fault. It picks the site where you're a mod and have the highest rep. For me it's Programmers'.

Comment: @ChrisF, I agree, that is what it does.  I think it would be more useful on chat.stackexchange to link to the more generic stackexchange.com profile.  Or at least make it optional.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/what-is-the-point-of-the-parent-user-in-chat (this question is older, but the answers in mine contain more up-to-date information)

Comment: @jtbandes, I would argue that it isn't a duplicate since I am asking for a change, the other question was asking for an explanation.  This question is also a year older, so the other question might be the duplicate.

Comment: @ChriF: The why does mine link to DBA.SE? I am not very active there and my rep is really low...