# Permanently kicked myself out of chat room by changing chat parent user

Tags: support, chat, moderator-abilities

So, in screwing around with the settings for chat (as a result of the activity in the mod chat room today), I changed my parent user, a diamond moderator on Academia.SE, to my SO profile, which does not have a diamond. As a result, I was booted from the mod chat room. However, changing the profile back didn't re-allow entry. Is this by design? I'm kinda confused about the whole "parent user" bit to begin with.

Comment: Short answer: the "parent user" thing is a bit of a cludge, and you ran into it face-first. Long answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/what-is-the-point-of-the-parent-user-in-chat/127993#127993

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing your parent user didn't automatically refresh your chat profile, so you weren't considered a chat mod. It automatically syncs every hour or so, so it would've figured it out eventually, but I forced it to refresh now so you should be able to join again. I don't know if this is by design or not

Comment: Definitely by-design. Keeps Aarthi guessing longer this way.

Comment: Kinda by design, but not really. Also part of [this bigger story](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127993/115866). @Shog's answer will do until that's done.