# Show the avatar of related site of a chat-room instead of parent site of a user

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-picture

Currently, in the chat-rooms the avatar is shown from the parent site that a user selected in the chat profile. So, throughout SE network in (any) chat-room (talking about main chat server i.e not MSE or SO), the same avatar is shown.

But as we know, sometimes users don't use the same avatar on all communities, but use different avatars according to the site. So, I think **when a user enters the chat-room, the avatar from the site related to that chat-room should be shown**.

As the chat-room is *nicely* related to specific site and users want the avatar according to the specific site, chat-room should use the avatar of related site of chat-room instead of using the same avatar of a parent site in all communities.

Note: In case the user doesn't have account on the site related to chat-room, use avatar of parent site.

Comment: I don't know if you already use "avatar" in a broader sense than "profile picture" here, but this should *definitely* also include using the *username* of the related site together with the profile picture. Otherwise it just gets even more confusing.

Comment: @ChristianRau Thanks for pointing out. Looks violating the [point of Parent User](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127993/260388)!

Comment: Well, yeah, exactly. The whole parent user system is somewhat of a legacy hack that should be abolished entirely anyway.