# When I type "chat.stackexchange.com" into my browser, why do I get a Blender-specific window?

Tags: discussion, support

This is the second time this has happened to me. When I type `chat.stackexchange.com` into a new Chrome incognito tab, I get a selection of chat rooms specific to Blender SE. I haven't visited there very recently, at least not in this session. Usually when I do this I get a generic chat site and I start typing search terms to get the site-specific chat room I'm looking for.

Cosmic rays?

Or is this expected behavior and the Blender discussions are just particularly active, so the logo appears but that doesn't mean very much?

If I click all, I get a more generic view, so I don't see this in any way problematic, I'm just asking why this happens the way that it does with the `site` tab selected and apparently `site=Blender`.

[image]

After clicking all:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're logged in, and your chat profile's parent account is your Blender account:

[image]

When you're logged in on the chat homepage you see your parent site's rooms...

For example, my parent site is Graphic Design and I see:

[image]

Comment: I had no idea I had a parent site, thank you! I'll look into it now and see what's happening there. It's a credit to SE that things work so well even for people who don't read all of the instructions first :)

Comment: Well, the "instructions" for chat aren't as good as the rest of the network, and the whole parent user thing is a bit of a mess really, you can change it easily enough though if needs be

Comment: Coming from graphic design, I hope you don't find my user image too disturbing. I was going for horrid/kitsch with overtones of mathematics: https://youtu.be/I6cgca4Mmcc

Comment: What's a parent site? Is it simply the site where you've got your maximum rep?

Comment: @NVZ each chat account needs a "parent" SE user account, you can change it to any account you want, but other than the behaviour shown here and showing that site when you hover over a users avatar it doesn't really do much... See [What is the point of the “Parent User” in Chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127988/307988)