# What do the SE site symbols in chat (on user profiles) mean?

Tags: support, chat, chat-profile, parent-user

In chat (if relevant, I first saw this on "[the h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar)" from Physics SE, though it shows in other rooms as well), there is a list of active users and those who have been in the chat room recently. When you click on one of their profile pictures, a small popup shows with links to their profiles and their activity stats shows. For example, for me it looks like this:

[image]

(there usually is also a sort of diagram which I think shows the user's participation in chat – it is not there for me since I have never talked in chat before)

I wondered what the symbol in the upper right corner means. On my profile, it is the [Photo SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) logo. Why is this logo on my user profile? My first thought was that it is the logo of the SE site where the user has the most reputation, but that would be Physics for me.

So what decides which logo will show on the user profile in chat?

Comment: That would be called the parent site of your chat user, the first site from which you visited that particular chat server. There are multiple chatservers (Stackexchange, stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange)

Comment: See [What is the point of the “Parent User” in Chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127988/355458) - possible duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Those represent your parent site

For more information on the parent site, check out [this other meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/what-is-the-point-of-the-parent-user-in-chat)