# Wearing a wrong hat in Winter Bash 2021 chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

I'm wearing a wrong hat in Winter Bash 2021 chatroom.

Currently on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/379623/debanjanb) I am wearing the *Dialogue* hat.

[image: Dialoge_Hat]

Where as in [Winter Bash 2021 chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132350/winter-bash-2021) I'm wearing the *Kitsune* hat.

[image: Kitsune_Hat]

Comment: I think that's because your [chat parent user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127988/154375) is the one from StackOverflow, where you are indeed wearing the Kitsune hat.

Comment: @Adinia If chatrooms like [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) can be created based on parent  _Meta Stack Exchange_ why can't be chatrooms like [Winter Bash 2021](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132350/winter-bash-2021) be created with similar parent instead of parent as _Stack Exchange_ or _StackOverflow_ ?